# AngularJs factory and controller flow of control

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need some help understanding the code below. It is taken from:

> http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets

**Factory:**

```
app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
var socket = io.connect();
  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      socket.on(eventName, function () {  
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          if (callback) {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        });
      })
    }
  };
```

**Controller:**

```
function AppCtrl($scope, socket) {

  // Socket listeners
  // ================

  socket.on('init', function (data) {
    $scope.name = data.name;
    $scope.users = data.users;
  });

  $scope.sendMessage = function () {
    socket.emit('send:message', {
      message: $scope.message
    });

    // add the message to our model locally
    $scope.messages.push({
      user: $scope.name,
      text: $scope.message
    });

    // clear message box
    $scope.message = '';
  };
}
```

**My doubt is:**

1. What is the flow of control once the controller calls `socket.on('init',function(data){.....});`. In factory when `socket.on` is called it takes two parameters eventName and callback. What is this callback?
2. Why are we using `$rootScope.apply`
3. What is `callback.apply`?

Comment: read this link http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.What is the flow of control once the controller calls socket.on('init',function(data){.....});. In factory when socket.on is called it takes two parameters eventName and callback. What is this callback?

There is nothing special involved in calling `socket.on` from your controller. Doing that simply calls the `on` method in the factory, directly.

Once that's clear, it's easy to see that `callback` is simply the second parameter passed into that function. In the case of this example, it's the function `function (data) {  $scope.name = data.name;  $scope.users = data.users; }`

> 2.Why are we using $rootScope.apply

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

To ensure that anything that happens in the function inside it is picked up in a digest cycle.

> 3.What is callback.apply?

It's the [apply method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) that's present on any JavaScript function. This is being used here to call the `callback` with the socket as the `this` parameter and the event handler's arguments as the arguments.